# Using clamav efficiently when timeshift snapshots are present

Tags: linux-mint, hard-link, clamav

I am searching for a simple way to perform a full system scan using clamav on a machine that also has Timeshift based snapshooting enabled.

[As suggested by this answer on the Ubuntu site](https://askubuntu.com/a/560947), I was using a command like:

```
clamscan -r --bell -i -exclude-dir="^/sys" /
```

(note: the `-exclude-dir="^/sys"` param was suggested to me by another user that pointed out that /sys is a virtual directory and probably best excluded from scans to avoid possible read-access errors)

The command works as expected, 'check all files on the computer, but only display infected files and ring a bell when found'.

This has an evident problem: "all files on the computer" includes the "/timeshift" directory, which is the directory Timeshift use to store snapshot data.

Now, taken from Timeshift official page:

> In RSYNC mode, **snapshots are taken using rsync and hard-links. Common files are shared between snapshots** which saves disk space. Each snapshot is a full system backup that can be browsed with a file manager.

To put it simply: Timeshift duplicates the changed files, and uses hard-links to reference the unchanged ones. As far as my understanding go, this means that the "first" snapshot is probably a full copy of the filesystem (obviously excluding any file/path that Timeshift is configured to ignore) while any following snapshot only includes the changed files and mere links to to unchanged ones.

The problem: under standard settings, clamscan will also scan EVERY file in the /timeshift folder. While I am fine with scanning the changed files which are actual real files... scanning the links seems a waste since basically it means scanning the same file multiple times - one for the snapshot the file was first changed for, and then one for each link to the unchanged file in the following snapshots.

I am therefore searching for a simple way to exclude those hard-links from the scan. `man clamscan` shows the existence of a `--follow-file-symlinks` option, but even doing

```
clamscan -r --bell -i -exclude-dir="^/sys" --follow-file-symlinks=0 /
```

doesn't seem to work. After all, as far as my understanding go, that option only excludes **symlinks**, while Timeshift is using **hard-links**.

So, my question is: **is there any way to perform a full system scan while skipping scanning the hard-linked files in the /timeshift directory while at the same time scanning the real ones?**

(as a bonus side-question: would the same be possible using the clamtk UI too?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard links to files are indistinguishable from what you call "real files" - it's actually same file which lies in two directories. Best solution in your case would be just to add one more `-exclude-dir="^/timeshift"` parameter to the `clamscan` command.

Comment: Ok, I have done some more research and now I understand the whole hard-link concept a little better. I see what's your point. I guess that achieving this behavior would require rewriting the scan engine to take hard links in consideration - basically building a sort of "already scanned inodes" table. Guess that I will have to live with the exclusion for now.